# How can I determine the subject of an rspec controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, tdd, rspec-rails

So I don't have a great reason for needing to know this other than curiosity - the BEST reason - but I'm not sure what's going on here.

**Background:**
I'm working through the RSpec book and updating the examples.

On Chapter 24 - Rails Controllers there's a test for a messages controller.

```
## spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb ##

require 'spec_helper'

describe MessagesController do
  describe "POST create" do
    let(:message) { mock_model(Message).as_null_object }

    before do
      Message.stub(:new).and_return(message)
    end

  # Then a bunch of Tests...

    context "when the message fails to save" do
      before do
        message.stub(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create
      end

      it "assigns @message" do
        assigns[:message].should eq(message)
      end

      it "renders the new template" do
        response.should render_template("new")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This goes along with the messages controller:

```
## app/controllers/messages_controller.rb ##

class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "The message was saved successfully"
      redirect_to action: "index"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the tests:
The test passes with **response**.

```
it "renders the new template" do
  response.should render_template("new")
end
```

The test also passes with **subject**.

```
it "renders the new template" do
  subject.should render_template("new")
end
```

The test Also passes with **page**

```
it "renders the new template" do
  page.should render_template("new")
end
```

The test ALSO passes with **NOTHING**

```
it "renders the new template" do
 should render_template("new")
end
```

In case it helps anyone make heads or tails of this, the `config/routes.rb` just has  `resources :messages` 

Why do all those tests pass? What am I actually testing? Are 'page', 'subject', and ' ' just synonyms for response? 
Does it matter as long as my tests pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the subject would be referencing the class, which is the MessagesController.

Not defining a subject in the last test example, will implicitly set the subject to be MessagesController.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but it's mostly my fault for not being clearer. What is the response? What is actually happening here. Is response just an object attached to the MessagesController class? Sorry to ask for the clarification. I want to accept the answer but I still don't understand what's happening here.

Comment: Looking at the doc, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object, is the response of the MessagesController class, in testing controllers, if you the `it ... do` block will define the subject to be the class itself, which in term should equate to the response object i believe

Answer (score 0):

From a binding.pry, it appears that subject is an *instance of* the controller class:

```
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyController::DescribeString::ContextString>)> subject.is_a? Class
=> false
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyController::DescribeString::ContextString>)> subject.is_a? Users::SessionsController
=> true
```