# RSpec Rails - subject + assigns as one liner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am struggling with the following RSpec. Why does this works:

```
   it 'GET articles#new creates new instance of Article' do
    get :new
    expect(assigns[:article]).to be_a(Article)
  end
```

And neither of those do (found some examples with different brackets and that's why I decided to check both possibilities)

```
  subject { get :new }
  it { expect(assigns[:article]).to be_a(Article) }
  it { expect(assigns(:article)).to be_a(Article) }
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Failure/Error: it { expect(assigns(:article)).to be_a(Article) }
   expected nil to be a kind of Article(id: integer, title: string, body: string, author_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
 # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't know how to retrieve "article" from the subject...

I have also tried some various combinations of "subject" and "assigns" inside it { ... }, but I couldn't get it working.

I'd rather keep it clean and store it in one line only :)

BTW: Do you have any other habits of writing Specs for controllers? (I already check for response 200)

Comment: Single line examples are discouraged by the current maintainers of RSpec. You are best advised to use the more descriptive form as in Sovalina's answer.

Comment: @PaulByrne does the same rule applies if I have specified 'context', 'describe' and 'subject' and I just wanted to have 'it' in one line?

Comment: Yeah, it's not a rule. But readability and maintainability are improved by including a descriptive string for your example. YMMV

Comment: @PaulByrne thank you, will take it into consideration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs), a controller spec :

> allows you to simulate a single http request in each example, and then
>   specify expected outcomes such as:
>
> - instance variables assigned in the controller to be shared with the    view

that's why you have to run the request (like `get :new`) inside the `it` block to return the correct output.

If you define the request as the subject of your spec (precision about `subject` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028878/9541423)), you need to run the subject inside the `it` block :

```
subject { get :new }

it 'GET articles#new creates new instance of Article' do
  subject
  expect(assigns[:article]).to be_a(Article)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`subject`, like `let` is lazy-evaluated only when you are referencing it. You can use `subject!` instead, which will be evaluated before each example